# Web Parts with a markup file?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I'm an ASP.NET web part novice.  I've built a few simple ones using only a class that derived from WebPart and overriding the CreateChildControls method, but nothing really very substantial.  My question is whether it's possible to have a web part that also takes advantage of a separate html/asp.net markup file that will help provide some structure to the web part's output.  In the past I just created server controls and added them to the controls collection, but this seems like a silly way to try to create a non-trivial layout.  Can I do this?  Do I have to use an ascx user control or can I bypass that step?  There are a lot of hello world tutorials on web parts out there, but none seem to go past the CreateChildControls override.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Go [here](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/ViewPost.aspx?PostId=248) to learn about templated web parts, and go [here](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/ShowCategory.aspx?categoryId=24) to see all of the info he has on WebParts. I used this technique back in 2004/2005 and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

The links in the above answer are no longer working, but here is an alternative one:
http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=95

In VS 2010 we also have visual web parts, that I think do pretty much the same trick but it's wrapped in a project item. I've only seen this in the context of SharePoint so not sure how it works for ASP.NET projects. Here is an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597539.aspx